# How can I perform these MySQL subqueries in a cleaner way?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

*Using legacy code which uses `mysql` instead of `mysqli/pdo` so don't worry about this, I'll update the queries for this later.*

Even though my current method works, I'm positive there is a cleaner way of doing this rather than a query and 3 subqueries. I mainly want to learn how to better enhance my queries and minimizing the amount of them.
What I'm trying to do is

1. `echo` out all the data for each date with the date displayed on top
2. Display the count of entries for each user on that particular day next to the user
3. For each date, at the bottom of the above 2 bits of data, display the user/s with the highest number of entries

   ```
   $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM entries GROUP BY DATE(dt)');

   $g = 0;

   while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
   {

       $group[$g] = date('y-m-d', strtotime($row['dt']));
       echo $group[$g] . "<br />";

       //display the person's name for today with their count
       $dayquery = mysql_query('SELECT *, COUNT(username) as total FROM entries WHERE DATE(dt) = "'.$group[$g].'" GROUP BY username ORDER BY COUNT(username) DESC');
           while ($today = @mysql_fetch_array($dayquery)) 
           {
               echo $today['first_name'] . " | " . $today['total'] . "<br />";
           }   

           //display the highest count for today
           $topquery = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(username) as highest FROM entries WHERE DATE(dt) = "'.$group[$g].'" GROUP BY username ORDER BY COUNT(username) DESC LIMIT 1');
               while ($toptoday = @mysql_fetch_array($topquery)) 
               {
                   echo "Highest today: " . $toptoday['highest'] . "<br /><br />" ;
               } 

               //display the users with the highest count for today
               echo "Highest users: ";
               $userstopquery = mysql_query('SELECT *, COUNT(username) as total FROM entries WHERE DATE(dt) = "'.$group[$g].'" AND COUNT(username) = "' . $toptoday['highest'] . '" AND GROUP BY username');
                   while ($topusers = @mysql_fetch_array($userstopquery)) 
                   {
                        echo $topusers['first_name'] . "<br />" ;
                   } 

       $g++;

   }
   ```

The trouble I'm having is that when I try and reduce these subqueries and use `MAX` it will only output the highest count but not all the data for each date,  which is what I need, including output of the user/s with the most amount of entries for that given day.

Comment: Simple. See JOIN. But the first query is (potentially) nonsensical.

Comment: Well you can get the answer to query 2 from either the first or last row of query 1, depending on how you sort the results of query 1. Also the answer to query 3 is in the result of query 1. So assuming query 1 works you can get rid of query 2 and 3 completely

Comment: @Strawberry how can I use a JOIN in this instance to clean it up?

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you provide an example as an answer? Would it be using num rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with something like this. Note that I'm not using PHP's mysql_ API as it was deprecated 3 or 4 years ago...

```
require('path/to/mysqli/connection/stateme.nts');

$array = array();

$query = "
SELECT e.dt
     , e.username
     , COUNT(*) ttl
  FROM entries e
 GROUP
    BY e.dt
     , e.username
 ORDER 
    BY e.dt, ttl DESC;
";


$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            $array[] = $row;
        }

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Wow - Thanks Strawberry! If I now loop and echo out the data will it provide me with the data separated by day and also the top users for that day? If not, would be great to see how you would go about it. Everything in one query is so confusing!

Comment: Yes. The first result for each day will be the top one.

Comment: Unfortunately that only prints out all the data as an array but doesn't display the usernames and their count for each day. The first result for each day displays ttl as 1 but that is not correct as it is not a count of all their entries. What it should display is: `[date]<br />[username] | [Count for this day], [next username] | [Count for this day]` so that for each day and then for each day also display the user/s with the most count for that particular day like `Most entries for [date]<br />[username] and [username]`.

Comment: If you need something else, select something else. I've demonstrated a principle which should be fairly easy to adapt to your purpose. There's a skill to understanding the difference between data display and data storage and retrieval, the latter being the domain of MySQL and the former being (in this instance) the domain of PHP.

Comment: @Srawberry Ah I see. In this instance it is purely for data display, hence the focus is more on the PHP side but using MySQL for retrieval. Based on my original code, is it possible to show me a cleaner way of doing exactly that? (Instead of in arrays etc.)

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76841/discussion-between-dt-dtdg-and-strawberry).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, easier to explain on chat which I now have.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of chats. If you like, consider editing your question to provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH a desired result set.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer. Ended up parsing the array and outputting the desired results. Works like a charm now :) Thank you!